# DropDownList cascating mvc 4 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:Content ID="Javascript" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $("#estados").change(function () {
                var uf = listaCidade($(this).val());

            });            
        });        
        //chamada ajax para a Action ListaCidade        
        //passando como parâmetro a Estado selecionado        
        function listaCidade(uf) {

            // <%=Url.Action("listaCidade")%>
            $.getJSON('/AdmPaginaBranca/listaCidade/' + uf, listaCidadeCallBack);

        }
        //função que irá ser chamada quando terminar        
        //a chamada ajax 

        function listaCidadeCallBack(json) {
            //Limpar os itens que são maiores que 0            
            //Ou seja: não retirar o primeiro item   

            $("#cidades:gt(0)").remove();            
            $(json).each(function () {
                //adicionando as opções de acordo com o retorno                
                $("#cidades").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.nome + "</option>");

            });            
        }   
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult listaCidade(int id)
{
    return Json(new cidadeEstadoDAO().CarregarComboCidade(id));
}
```

error: GET http://localhost/AdmPaginaBranca/listaCidade/13 500 (Internal Server Error)

I need some help to make this work code. It is taking place this error 500. I'm desperate

Comment: Use you browser tools (Network tab) to see the details of the error

Comment: "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."

Comment: Then add it! - `return Json(new cidadeEstadoDAO().CarregarComboCidade(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: unable to operate the return according to the selected state . But in dropdownlist is " undefinied " is failing to mount the dropdownlist with cities : /